# ffmpeg and inline video device name

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

Usually when you have to record a video with ffmpeg use an "already installed" device.

You can retrieve the list of already installed devices with:
c:> ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i

```
dummy
ffmpeg version N-45279-g6b86dd5... 
[dshow @ 03ACF580] DirectShow video devices
[dshow @ 03ACF580]  "Integrated Camera"
[dshow @ 03ACF580]  "screen-capture-recorder"
[dshow @ 03ACF580] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 03ACF580]  "Internal Microphone (Conexant 2"
[dshow @ 03ACF580]  "virtual-audio-capturer"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

once I've done that I can record one of them:

```
c:\> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" out.mp4
```

But if the device isn't already installed, but I have only the ax file, what can I do? It would perfect something like this

```
c:\> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=./myDevice.ax out.mp4
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just register the device with regsvr32 before running ffmpeg?

Comment: It is a simple application, and I'm just a beginner. I'm afraid of compatibility issues ( w7, vista, w8, 32/64bit ) and permission management to use regsvr32 ( need to ask admin privileges to the user ). Do you think that I'm worrying of anything?

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to register it for it to show up in directshow.  if you just want to capture screen, FFMpeg has a "gdigrab" internal option that doesn't require registration...